# Next Steps for Social Networking

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Now that we have a [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/buddhism.se), a [Google Plus page](https://plus.google.com/b/108433255070820808315/108433255070820808315/), and a [Twitter account](https://twitter.com/Buddhism_SE), we should probably figure out the proper steps to take in regards to administering these resources. Specifically:

- Is it okay for us to maintain such resources? I'm just asking in case I may have missed some SE rule against creating our own "official" SE pages on other sites.
- Assuming it is okay, who should be the administrators? I assume the best would be to make the current moderators admins, and just switch when they change. Any thoughts on this?
- Can anyone offer to create a PD image to use as the profile pic and cover banner for the accounts?

I'm thinking we can post updates like a blog on our pages; I'm not sure if we get an SE blog when we go official (I don't think so), so it will give us a chance to provide updates to the community as appropriate (like reaching our 90 day landmark and almost meeting the criteria!)

Answer (score 3):

You must not create an "official" SE page: [see this answer for detail](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/313/254).

Social Networking owned by the site might not be useful: [see also this comment for detail](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307/social-media-accounts#comment491_307).

"Social" networking might be better done by people, using their existing social networks: you (each person) mention this site on your own blog, your own Facebook or Twitter account, to your own friends and 'followers'.

Comment: Thanks; somehow I missed that answer.